# Issue in merging angular-datatable with the drag-drop directives

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am having some problem with Column reordering in angular-datatable([angular-datatables](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables)),

Please have a look at : [angular-datatable column draggable out of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442206/angular-datatable-column-draggable-out-of-the-table), 
to better understand the question.

So I could able to find a simple drag-drop/column-reorder directives that does exactly what I wanted.

link: 
 [ColumnReordering](http://plnkr.co/edit/KvJglc?p=preview)
(This has the neat drag-drop/column-reordering implementation)

So tried to couple with angular-datatable, which you can find it here
[angular-dataTable Integration](http://plnkr.co/edit/gQkBUg0XMl59eXYZLLYB?p=preview)

Steps I did with the first plunker to integrate the angular-datatable:

**In index.html**

- < script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" />
- < script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
- <
  script  src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.11/angular.js" />
- < script src="http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"
  />

**Added `datatables` in the DI**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['datatables'] );
```

**Added  `datatable="ng"` in tabletemplate.html**

```
<table   datatable="ng" class="acttable" border="1">
    <thead>
      <th style="cursor:move" draggable drag="handleDrag"  dragData="{{hd}}" dragImage="{{dragImageId}}" droppable drop="handleDrop" ng-repeat="hd in conf.heads"><span>{{hd}}</span>
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="data in conf.myData">
        <td ng-repeat="d in conf.heads"><span>{{data[d]}}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Problem Is column reordering is happening, but there is no `datatable` features affecting , Can see errors in web console. 
Could not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: I dont see anything in the plnkrs that relate to dataTables nor ColReorder? You seem more to implement a compltely different drag-drop directive, and that will never work with dataTables.  However, I have answered your prior question with a working example.

Comment: @davidkonrad can you provide link to your answer pls?

Comment: @TheRebel -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442206/angular-datatable-column-draggable-out-of-the-table