# Reordering columns in angular-datatables

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

Is there any way to reorder angular-datatable colums?

The ideal way would be drag & dropping but I can't find anywhere this kind of option.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to use the `ColReorder` extension, see this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442206/angular-datatable-column-draggable-out-of-the-table

Comment: @davidkonrad Thanks for your help, write the answer and I will accept it as the correct one.